# What's is wrong with this dagger2 simple example?

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

**1 - Scope:**

```
@Scope
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.CLASS)
public @interface PerInstance {}
```

**2 - AppContextModule:**

```
@Module
public class AppContextModule {

Application application;

public AppContextModule(Application application){
    this.application = application;
}

@Provides
public Application application(){
    return this.application;
}

@Provides
public Context context(){
    return this.application;
}

@Provides
public LocationManager locationManager(Context context){
    return (LocationManager)      context.getSystemService(context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
}

}
```

**3 - MeuPrimeiroModule:**

```
@Module
public class MeuPrimeiroModule {

@Provides
@PerInstance
public String nome() {
    return new String("Gorick");
}

}
```

**4 - MeuSegundoModule:**

```
@Module(includes = MeuPrimeiroModule.class)
public class MeuSegundoModule {

@Provides
@Singleton
public String nomeCompleto(MeuPrimeiroModule meuPrimeiroModule) {
    return new String(meuPrimeiroModule + " Silva");
}

}
```

**5 - MeuPrimeiroComponent:**

```
@PerInstance
@Component(modules={MeuPrimeiroModule.class})
public interface MeuPrimeiroComponent {
void inject(MainActivity mainActivity);
}
```

**6 - MeuSegundoComponent:**

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules={MeuSegundoComponent.class})
public interface MeuSegundoComponent extends MeuPrimeiroComponent {

void inject(MainActivity mainActivity);
}
```

**7 - AppContextComponent:**

```
public interface AppContextComponent {

Application app(); //provision method
Context applicationContext(); //provision method
LocationManager locationManager(); //provision method
}
```

**8 - ApplicationComponent:**

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules={AppContextModule.class}) 
public interface ApplicationComponent extends AppContextComponent {
void inject(MainActivity mainActivity);
}
```

**9 - MainActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Inject
MeuPrimeiroComponent meuPrimeiroComponent;

@Inject
MeuSegundoComponent meuSegundoComponent;

TextView nome, nomeCompleto;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    nome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nome);
    nomeCompleto = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nomeCompleto);

    setNome(nome, nomeCompleto);
}

public void setNome(TextView nome, TextView nomeCompleto){
    nome.setText(meuPrimeiroComponent.toString());
    nomeCompleto.setText(meuSegundoComponent.toString());
}

}
```

**Build:**

```
Error:(16, 10) error: gorick.dagger2.Dagger2.Component.MeuPrimeiroComponent cannot be provided without an @Provides- or @Produces-annotated method.
gorick.dagger2.Dagger2.Component.MeuPrimeiroComponent is injected at
gorick.dagger2.MainActivity.meuPrimeiroComponent
gorick.dagger2.MainActivity is injected at
gorick.dagger2.Dagger2.Component.ApplicationComponent.inject(mainActivity)
```

PS: If i use meuPrimeiroComponent.nome(), android studio doesn't find the nome() method.

Comment: From where your injecting `MainActivity` ?

Comment: From MeuPrimeiroComponent.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot inject values in component instead you need to inject in object whose constructor contains values which is returns by the providers

For more info Ref this [Example](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Dependency-Injection-with-Dagger-2)

You need build Component like this on `onCreate()`:

```
DaggerMeuPrimeiroComponent.builder()
                // list of modules that are part of this component need to be created here too
                .appContextModule(new AppContextModule(getApplicationContext())) // This also corresponds to the name of your module: %component_name%Module
                .build().inject(this);
```

Comment: I didn't understand very well your answer.

Comment: I have edited my answer and provided you the example